# A quote from an integration textbook: Anyone know the source?

Tags: reference-request

Long ago I saw a quote in a textbook on the Lebesgue integral.  Here is
the quote the author used:

> *There are nine and sixty ways of constructing tribal lays,
>
>   And--every--single--one--of--them--is--right.*
>   Rudyard Kipling,  **In
>   the Neolithic Age**  (1892).

Kipling is alluding to literary controversies and the textbook author meant to apply this to the well-known situation that the Lebesgue integral can be and has been developed in more than  a dozen ways.

My question is just which textbook and which author was this?  I want to refer to it and cannot without knowing this.  Surely it was a British author from an earlier generation that would have been more literate than I.

Answer (score 4):

There is a book: "[The Structure of Lebesgue Integration Theory](http://shp.primebrands.eu/freebooks/download/asin=019853146X&type=stream)" by George Temple that uses this quote. He is indeed an English mathematician and it seems like [he had an interesting life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Frederick_James_Temple)! Is this the book you are thinking of?

Comment: That's it.  Many thanks.